# Parsing Map of 0 items Map (0 Items)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am learning how to work with JSON and I have run into another situation.
I am getting a JSON payload from an API and display it below:

```
[
{
"addressLine1":"2880 La Quinta Dr",
"city":"Missouri City",
"state":"TX",
"zipCode":"77459",
"formattedAddress":"2880 La Quinta Dr, Missouri City, TX 77459",
"county":"Fort Bend",
"features":{},  <<<<<<<<<  ERROR OCCURS HERE  >>>>>>>>>>
"id":"2880-La-Quinta-Dr,-Missouri-City,-TX-77459",
"longitude":-95.551958,
"latitude":29.578265
}
]
```

The JSON is a single List of multiple Maps. In the example above I am only showing one element of the List for simplicity.

This is the code where I am parsing the JSON into a List by calling the method, PropertyInformation():

```
try {
      var url = Uri.parse(
          "https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties?zipCode=77459");
          //"https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties?address=5500%20Grand%20Lake%20Dr%2C%20San%20Antonio%2C%20TX%2C%2078244");
      final response = await client.get(
        url,
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key':
              '51ced1b32emsh509f82e1d58ae16p1ad6e6jsn75d75166a8b4',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com'
        },
      );
      //log("response  $response");
      log("response body ${response.body}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // decode the json
        for (var i in jsonData) {
          log("i $i");
          propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));
        }

      } else {
        print('Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = false;
      });
      log("error $e");
    }
```

This is the data passed to PropertyInformation:

```
Map (11 items)
0:"addressLine1" -> "6155 Sienna Ranch Rd"
1:"city" -> "Missouri City"
2:"state" -> "TX"
3:"zipCode" -> "77459"
4:"formattedAddress" -> "6155 Sienna Ranch Rd, Missouri City, TX 77459"
5:"county" -> "Fort Bend"
6:"features" -> Map (0 items)
7:"lastSaleDate" -> "2012-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"
8:"id" -> "6155-Sienna-Ranch-Rd,-Missouri-City,-TX-77459"
9:"longitude" -> -95.548935
10:"latitude" -> 29.540808
```

As you can see, element #6 is a Map (0 items)

This is the code where the class PropertyInformation:

```
class PropertyInformation {
  String? addressLine1;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? formattedAddress;
  String? assessorId;
  int? bedrooms;
  String? county;
  String? legalDescription;
  int? squareFootage;
  String? subdivision;
  int? yearBuilt;
  int? bathrooms;
  int? lotSize;
  String? propertyType;
  DateTime? lastSaleDate;
  Features? features;
  Map<String?, TaxAssessment> taxAssessment;
  Map<String?, PropertyTax> propertyTaxes;
  Owner? owner;
  String? id;
  double? longitude;
  double? latitude;

  PropertyInformation({
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.formattedAddress,
    required this.assessorId,
    required this.bedrooms,
    required this.county,
    required this.legalDescription,
    required this.squareFootage,
    required this.subdivision,
    required this.yearBuilt,
    required this.bathrooms,
    required this.lotSize,
    required this.propertyType,
    required this.lastSaleDate,
    required this.features,
    required this.taxAssessment,
    required this.propertyTaxes,
    required this.owner,
    required this.id,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.latitude,
  });

  factory PropertyInformation.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return PropertyInformation(
      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      formattedAddress: json['formattedAddress'],
      assessorId: json['assessorId'],
      bedrooms: json['bedrooms'],
      county: json['county'],
      legalDescription: json['legalDescription'],
      squareFootage: json['squareFootage'],
      subdivision: json['subdivision'],
      yearBuilt: json['yearBuilt'],
      bathrooms: json['bathrooms'],
      lotSize: json['lotSize'],
      propertyType: json['propertyType'],
      lastSaleDate: json['lastSaleDate'] == null ? DateTime.now() : DateTime.parse(json['lastSaleDate']),
      //features: Features.fromJson(json['features']),
      // features: Map.from(json['features']).map((k, v) =>
      //     MapEntry<String?, Features>(
      //         k, Features.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      features: json['features'].map((json)=>Features.fromJson(json)).toList(),
      taxAssessment: Map.from(json['taxAssessment']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, TaxAssessment>(
              k, TaxAssessment.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      propertyTaxes: Map.from(json['propertyTaxes']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, PropertyTax>(
              k, PropertyTax.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      owner: Owner.fromJson(json['owner']),
      id: json['id'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'addressLine1': addressLine1,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipCode,
      'formattedAddress': formattedAddress,
      'assessorId': assessorId,
      'bedrooms': bedrooms,
      'county': county,
      'legalDescription': legalDescription,
      'squareFootage': squareFootage,
      'subdivision': subdivision,
      'yearBuilt': yearBuilt,
      'bathrooms': bathrooms,
      'lotSize': lotSize,
      'propertyType': propertyType,
      'lastSaleDate': lastSaleDate?.toIso8601String(),
      //'features': features?.toJson(),
      'taxAssessment': taxAssessment
          .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String?, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      'propertyTaxes': propertyTaxes
          .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String?, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      'owner': owner?.toJson(),
      'id': id,
      'longitude': longitude,
      'latitude': latitude,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    //return 'PropertyInformation{addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, formattedAddress: $formattedAddress, assessorId: $assessorId, bedrooms: $bedrooms, county: $county, legalDescription: $legalDescription, squareFootage: $squareFootage, subdivision: $subdivision, yearBuilt: $yearBuilt, bathrooms: $bathrooms, lotSize: $lotSize, propertyType: $propertyType, lastSaleDate: $lastSaleDate, features: $features, taxAssessment: $taxAssessment, propertyTaxes: $propertyTaxes, owner: $owner, id: $id, longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude}';
    return 'PropertyInformation{addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, formattedAddress: $formattedAddress, assessorId: $assessorId, bedrooms: $bedrooms, county: $county, legalDescription: $legalDescription, squareFootage: $squareFootage, subdivision: $subdivision, yearBuilt: $yearBuilt, bathrooms: $bathrooms, lotSize: $lotSize, propertyType: $propertyType, lastSaleDate: $lastSaleDate, taxAssessment: $taxAssessment, propertyTaxes: $propertyTaxes, owner: $owner, id: $id, longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude}';
  }
}

class Features {
  String? architectureType;
  bool? cooling;
  String? coolingType;
  String? exteriorType;
  int? floorCount;
  String? foundationType;
  bool? garage;
  String? garageType;
  bool? heating;
  String? heatingType;
  bool? pool;
  String? roofType;
  int? roomCount;
  int? unitCount;

  Features({
    required this.architectureType,
    required this.cooling,
    required this.coolingType,
    required this.exteriorType,
    required this.floorCount,
    required this.foundationType,
    required this.garage,
    required this.garageType,
    required this.heating,
    required this.heatingType,
    required this.pool,
    required this.roofType,
    required this.roomCount,
    required this.unitCount,
  });

  factory Features.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return Features(
      architectureType: json['architectureType'],
      cooling: json['cooling'],
      coolingType: json['coolingType'],
      exteriorType: json['exteriorType'],
      floorCount: json['floorCount'],
      foundationType: json['foundationType'],
      garage: json['garage'],
      garageType: json['garageType'],
      heating: json['heating'],
      heatingType: json['heatingType'],
      pool: json['pool'],
      roofType: json['roofType'],
      roomCount: json['roomCount'],
      unitCount: json['unitCount'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'architectureType': architectureType,
      'cooling': cooling,
      'coolingType': coolingType,
      'exteriorType': exteriorType,
      'floorCount': floorCount,
      'foundationType': foundationType,
      'garage': garage,
      'garageType': garageType,
      'heating': heating,
      'heatingType': heatingType,
      'pool': pool,
      'roofType': roofType,
      'roomCount': roomCount,
      'unitCount': unitCount,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Features{architectureType: $architectureType, cooling: $cooling, coolingType: $coolingType, exteriorType: $exteriorType, floorCount: $floorCount, foundationType: $foundationType, garage: $garage, garageType: $garageType, heating: $heating, heatingType: $heatingType, pool: $pool, roofType: $roofType, roomCount: $roomCount, unitCount: $unitCount}';
  }
}

class Owner {
  List<String?> names;
  MailingAddress mailingAddress;

  Owner({
    required this.names,
    required this.mailingAddress,
  });

  factory Owner.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return Owner(
      names: json['names'].cast<String?>(),
      mailingAddress: MailingAddress.fromJson(json['mailingAddress']),
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'names': names,
      'mailingAddress': mailingAddress.toJson(),
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Owner{names: $names, mailingAddress: $mailingAddress}';
  }
}

class MailingAddress {
  String? id;
  String? addressLine1;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? addressLine2;

  MailingAddress({
    required this.id,
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.addressLine2,
  });

  factory MailingAddress.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return MailingAddress(
      id: json['id'],
      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      addressLine2: json['addressLine2'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'addressLine1': addressLine1,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipCode,
      'addressLine2': addressLine2,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MailingAddress{id: $id, addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, addressLine2: $addressLine2}';
  }
}

class PropertyTax {
  int total;

  PropertyTax({
    required this.total,
  });

  factory PropertyTax.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return PropertyTax(
      total: json['total'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'total': total,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PropertyTax{total: $total}';
  }
}

class TaxAssessment {
  int value;
  int land;
  int improvements;

  TaxAssessment({
    required this.value,
    required this.land,
    required this.improvements,
  });

  factory TaxAssessment.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return TaxAssessment(
      value: json['value'],
      land: json['land'],
      improvements: json['improvements'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'value': value,
      'land': land,
      'improvements': improvements,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'TaxAssessment{value: $value, land: $land, improvements: $improvements}';
  }
}
```

The place where the execution throws an error is when it is trying to process a Map with 0 items. This is the line in the JSON where it fails and throws the error: **6:"features" -> Map (0 items)**

I have been Googling and searching for an answer but I have not come across this situation documented so far.

This is the code I have tried so far without success:

```
//features: Features.fromJson(json['features']),
      // features: Map.from(json['features']).map((k, v) =>
      //     MapEntry<String?, Features>(
      //         k, Features.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      features: json['features'].map((json)=>Features.fromJson(json)).toList(),
```

How do I process this one line of the JSON Map that is a Map of 0 items?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I added the code yu suggested but I had to add a ) at the end of the for statement and before the { as you can see below:

```
for (Map<String ,dynamic> feature in json['features']) {
      listOfFeatures.add(Features.fromJson(feature));
    };
```

And this is what I added to pass back:

```
features: listOfFeatures as Features,
```

When I execute the code now I get this error in the for statement, for (Map<String ,dynamic> feature in json['features']) at the json['features'] part:
_TypeError (type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable')

**UPDATE**

JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "addressLine1": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "state": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "zipCode": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "formattedAddress": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "assessorID": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "bedrooms": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "county": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "legalDescription": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "squareFootage": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "subdivision": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "yearBuilt": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "bathrooms": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "lotSize": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "propertyType": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lastSaleDate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "features": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "architectureType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "cooling": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "coolingType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "exteriorType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "floorCount": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "foundationType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "garage": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "garageType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "heating": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "heatingType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "pool": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "roofType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "roomCount": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "unitCount": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      },
      "taxAssessment": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "2018": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "land": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "improvements": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "2019": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "land": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "improvements": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "2020": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "land": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "improvements": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "2021": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "land": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "improvements": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "2022": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "land": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "improvements": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "propertyTaxes": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "2019": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "total": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "2021": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "total": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "names": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "mailingAddress": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "addressLine1": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "city": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "state": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "zipCode": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "longitude": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "latitude": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you return PropertyInformation create a list of Features and assign every element of the json['features'] individually.

```
List<Features> listOfFeatures = [];

for (Map<String ,dynamic> feature in json['features'] {
  listOfFeatures.add(Features.fromJson(feature));
}
```

and then return the list along with other properties.

```
features: listOfFeatures,
```

In the case your `json['features']` is emptied the forloop will not execute and what you return will be an empty list.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added a response to your code in the original post.

Comment: I guessed what happened here is the json['features'] itself is not a List but Map which is the reason why it failed to cast to List in the first place. Can you provide some examples of json['features'] content or format?

Comment: I added the JSON schema at the bottom of the original post. Thanks for your help